# Sudden rattling during acceleration, check engine light

Tags: noise, nissan, sparkplugs, cel, fuel-injection

I am trying to diagnose a problem, that suddenly occurred with my dci 2.0 Nissan Qashqai +2.

During acceleration, I heard a strange noise, after which the motor started sounding completely differently, much louder especially during acceleration in lower gear, lower power and with unstable speed. Check engine light is on (yellow) and after stopping the car it won't turn on any more, I can crank it, but it won't start.

I topped up on engine oil, but this didn't help.

From what I gathered, this is most likely the spark plugs or the fuel injection system. Since the car was able to drive home after the incident and can not be started at all after, is this an indication, that it is the spark plugs? After all the spark plugs are mainly needed when you start the car? On the other hand, why would the spark plugs be causing the other symptoms? What else could be going on? I didn't see any fluid leaking under the car.

Comment: You are just guessing until you get the codes read. It could be anything from a spark plug to a blown engine ... we don't really know.

Comment: Problem is the car is not movable, otherwise I would have driven by a service by now. Is it a good idea to invest in a code reader and read the code myself?

Comment: I entered "test mode" on the board computer (without reader) and it says "dtcs none". Does this mean the car forgot what happened? Does it still make sense to run a odb check?

Comment: You can get an ELM327 reader (Bluetooth for Android/WiFi for iPhone) and attach it to your phone. They are relatively cheap (about $15 here in the States) and are read only devices. Get the Torque Lite app for your phone, as it's free and you're all setup.

Comment: Thx, that is a very cheap solution indeed. So you would say to ignore the test mode results and check again with the tool?

Comment: It would be *glow* plugs rather than spark as it's a diesel engine - and you're correct in that they would only be used during starting so they aren't going to be your issue I'd have said. When the issue happened (and/or when driving afterwards) was there any sign of smoke from the exhaust? if so what color?

Comment: I didn't notice any smoke, but I didn't had a chance to look from outside.

Comment: One thing worth adding: When this happened, my car started to sound like a racing car or sports car. Maybe it is belt related?

Comment: It's extremely unlikely to be belt-related. Much more likely that it's exhaust or turbo related.

Comment: If it was exhaust, why wouldn't the engine start?

Comment: Well ODB Check shows no fault codes.